# Android: Java: Decrypt AES using key instead of password

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I'm using a snippet to decrypt an AES file.

However, i'd like to use a key file instead of a password to decrypt the file.

What changes do i need to make in the code below to make that happen?

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESCrypto {

    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
        return Converters.toHex(result);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = Converters.toByte(encrypted);
        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
        return new String(result);
    }

    public static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(seed);
        try {
            kgen.init(256, sr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.w(LOG, "This device doesn't support 256 bits, trying 192 bits.");
            try {
            kgen.init(192, sr);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            // Log.w(LOG, "This device doesn't support 192 bits, trying 128 bits.");
            kgen.init(128, sr);
            }
        }
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        return raw;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
            return encrypted;
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn crypto and don't use random snippets. That snippet may leave you with ciphertext that you'll never be able to decrypt anymore. And even if you could decrypt it, it's insecure.

Comment: I see it listed as the standard crypto code for android? Why is this code faulty?

Comment: *Could you please indicate **where** you find the above code "as the default crypto code for Android?"*. The problem is both with the `getRawKey` that uses a random number generator that *isn't deterministic nor well defined*, the implementation depends on the provider and it may - and has - changed without warning. Furthermore, you're using provider defaults for the mode of operation and padding by just asking for `Cipher.getInstance("AES")`. This is not deterministic either, and it usually defaults to the insecure ECB mode of encryption.

Comment: Actually, Android had an issue where the `SecureRandom` actually returned ... wait for it ... random values resulting in random AES keys. Now, since random AES keys can never be retrieved without breaking AES: bye bye plaintext.

Comment: Well, i thought i saw it on the developer.android.com but i cant find it now. 
So i see your recommendations, but being a noob, can you recommend how to improve the infringing code to make it better? Or just point to a better code sample that addresses these issues?

Comment: So you recommending i should use AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING instead?

Comment: And just to clarify, i need this to decrypt a file, not to encrypt one.

Comment: If you need to decrypt files you don't have any choice - you need to use the same method used for encryption, safe or not. What mode of encryption is used depends on what kind of protection is needed. Nowadays I would personally default to `"AES/GCM/NoPadding"` - or at least some kind of scheme with integrity/authentication of messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AES key is little more than 16, 24 or 32 bytes of randomly generated data. So to create a key file, save that amount of random data in it, and use it to instantiate `SecretKeySpec(byte[] data, "AES")`.

Note that for your convenience `SecretKeySpec` is also a `SecretKey`.